# Why do I get an "uninitialized constant" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, constants, rails-activerecord

I have the following code:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :rotting, :age
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :zombies, through: :assignments
end

class Assignments < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :role_id, :zombie_id
  belongs_to :zombie
  belongs_to :role
end
```

In the console, when I try to run this code:

```
zombie = Zombie.first
role = Role.first
zombie.assignments.create(role: role)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Zombie::Assignment.
```

Did I made any mistakes here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run following code on your console

```
zombie = Zombie.first
zombie.roles << Role.find_by_title("Title")
zombie.roles
```

Comment: This solution makes it work but does not solve the issue. Rails models are singular, consider changing `Assignments` to `Assignment`

Answer (score 4):

Rails models are singular, so change the class name `Assignments` to `Assignment`.

Comment: now i am getting this error ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: role

Comment: Only attr_accessible attributes are mass-assigned. In your case, role is not defined in attr_accessible. Better use,          'zombie.assignments.create(role_id: role)', also rails create role_id, and zombie_id as attr_accessible when you define **has_many through.** So         'attr_accessible :role_id, :zombie_id 'is unnecessary.